# How to get undordered list items into columns, with the text floating at the top

Tags: css

I often use the method

```
ul.col-list > li {width: 30%; display: inline-block;}
```

to get my `li`s into columns. The only problem is that if the text a list item spills onto the next line, then the text of the parallel list items is pushed down, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ayzwtujo/3/

Is there a quick fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) of your items so that the tops (or middles, it's up to you) are aligned:

```
ul.col-list > li {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayzwtujo/5/)

Comment: Damn @George... I can't type any faster and you still beat me!